# How to understand the parameter ttl of the database in cnosdb？

Tags: cnosdb

```
demoset ❯ create database demoset with ttl '1m' vnode_duration '1m';
demoset ❯ select * from air;
+-------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+
| time                          | station    | visibility | temperature | pressure |
+-------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+
| 2024-01-31T10:31:18.291665238 | XiaoMaiDao | 56.0       | 69.0        | 77.0     |
+-------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+
```

I created a database with ttl and vnode_duration of 1m. After inserting a piece of data, it does not disappear after one minute. Instead, it disappeared after two minutes.

I guess this has something to do with the parameters of ttl and vnode_duration. If the ttl I expect is the sum of the two, then how should I understand the ttl of the db parameter?